# keep file permissions for new files in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions

I need that the user *tom* can write/delete current log files and also log files created in the future by the user *owner* from the directory *for* in the path:
*/one/two/three/for/*.

The directory /for/ had these permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 owner owner 12288 Feb 27 10:17 for
```

The user *tom* belongs to the group *owner*.
I changed the permissions of the *for* directory with

```
chmod -R g+w for/*
```

so now i have

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 owner owner 12288 Feb 27 11:17 for
```

and the files inside the *for* directory have these permissions (664):

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 owner owner  2028593 Feb 28  2018 file
```

but after the creation of a new file it has still the old permissions (644):

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner  2028593 Feb 28  2018 newfile
```

Do you know the way to keep these permissions?
Thanks

Comment: the only way is to use the default acl?

Comment: How exactly do you create the new file? Maybe you have to set `umask` for the process that creates the file.

Answer (score 0):

I used *root* user but I found that I can delete it with the user *tom*. I didn't try it before. So it's solved. 
It inherits the permissions from the directory.
Thank you